# Rotation logs - How to add timestamp to log file name?

Tags: go, logging

Below code for rotation logs:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    lumberjack "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

func main() {
    logPath, _ := os.Getwd()
    log := NewLoggerFp(logPath, 1, 2, 2)

    log.Infof("sjkshfjsdf\n")
    log.Infof("sjkshfjsdf\n")
    log.Infof("sjkshfjsdf\n")
}

func NewLoggerFp(logPath string, maxSize, maxBackUp, maxAge int) *zap.SugaredLogger {

    w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{

        Filename:   logPath + "/dump.log",
        MaxSize:    maxSize, // megabytes
        MaxBackups: maxBackUp,
        MaxAge:     maxAge, // days
    })

    core := zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        w,
        zap.InfoLevel,
    )

    return zap.New(core).Sugar()
}
```

---

Logs get created
How to add timestamp to `dump.log`?

Answer (score 2):

I try to understand what Christian suggests. Maybe you can try this.

```
w := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{

    Filename:   logPath + fmt.Sprintf("/dump-%v.log", time.Now().Format(time.RFC822)),
    MaxSize:    maxSize, // megabytes
    MaxBackups: maxBackUp,
    MaxAge:     maxAge, // days
})
```

Comment: Subsequent file name gets messed up, if initial filename has timestamp

Comment: @d.moncada I configured as `Filename:   logPath + "/dump.log"`. Exclusing the first log file, subsequent log file names have timestamps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested it with a smaller MaxSize (or MaxAge) parameter?

According to https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2#example-Logger.Rotate, Lumberjack will append to the first file if the file exists and is less than MaxSize megabytes. When this limit is reached, timestamps are automatically added:

> Whenever a write would cause the current log file exceed MaxSize megabytes, the current file is closed, renamed, and a new log file created with the original name.
>
> Backups use the log file name given to Logger, in the form `name-timestamp.ext` where name is the filename without the extension, **timestamp is the time at which the log was rotated formatted with the time.Time format of `2006-01-02T15-04-05.000`** and the extension is the original extension.
>
> For example, if your Logger.Filename is `/var/log/foo/server.log`, a backup created at 6:30pm on Nov 11 2016 would use the filename `/var/log/foo/server-2016-11-04T18-30-00.000.log`
>
> **If the file exists and its size is >= MaxSize megabytes, the file is renamed by putting the current time in a timestamp in the name** immediately before the file's extension (or the end of the filename if there's no extension). A new log file is then created using original filename.

There is an open pull request to be able to customize the time stamp format: https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack/pull/118